# Element with z index -1 goes under grandparent's div

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index, absolute

Putting `z-index:-1` into absolute-child make the div under the grandparent. How do I make absolute-child go under the parent div not the grandparent div?

```css
.grandparent{
  background:rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.89);
  width:500px;
}

.parent{
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
}

.absolute-child{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  top:10px;
  right:-50px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="absolute-child"> absolute ch
      </div>
      <div class="siblings">siblings</div>
    </div>
 </div
```

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as check (helpfull)

Comment: @AwsmeSandy Can you explain it a little bit for me? Or suggest me an article to make myself clear.

Comment: If you are playing with the z-index with two elements, the you can give z-index to there parent as well, so the grandparent z-index acts as a base for there child divs.

Comment: @AwsmeSandy Any article to understand everything about z-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want, added `position: relative;` to the granparent so the `z-index: 0;` work for it.

```css
.grandparent{
  background:rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.89);
  width:500px;
      z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.parent{
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
}

.absolute-child{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    top: 10px;
    right: -50px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="absolute-child"> absolute ch
      </div>
      <div class="siblings">siblings</div>
    </div>
 </div
```